# Visual Studio profile function inside referenced dll

Tags: visual-studio, dll, profiling, cpu

After doing CPU profiling on my C# application in Visual Studio 2019 I realised that one of the function inside my DLL file consumes most of the CPU time.
Unfortunately I cannot see which part of the function is slow.
Normally I can see which line consumes the most in % like here:

[image: http://prntscr.com/s7wms3]

Unfortunately for functions in my DLL I cannot see this:

[image: http://prntscr.com/s7wol7]

Can someone please help to see the CPU consumption of each lines in functions for my DLLs?

Comment: Did you check memory usage?  The code may be running slow if the memory is being swapped onto a drive when you are using a lot of memory.

Comment: Yes, I still have like 8GB free memory while it is running.

Comment: Look like you are using Entity and querying a database.  So speed depends on the amount of data going from database, the query time in the database (size of database and keys in table),  type of database, speed of machine where database is located, speed of disk where data is stored, .......